# Does Passenger re-use database connection pools between requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, passenger

We have a master and a slave PostgreSQL databases. For read-only intensive parts (reporting) of the application, we use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:slave)` in a `before_action` controller block to direct request's queries to the slave.

After moving to this setup yesterday, we got a completely new error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute SELECT FOR UPDATE in a read-only transaction...`

This got us thinking. We are using Phusion Passenger 4.0.45 as the application server. Does the same Ruby/Rails instance re-use connection pools with Passenger?

In other words, if in one of the instances `establish_connection(:slave)` gets called, is it possible that this same instance serves another request where `establish_connection(:slave)` isn't explicitly called, but still uses the slave because of connection pool re-using or some other form of database connection caching?

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a Rails process reuses connections instantiated inside the same process. This is a Rails feature, not a Passenger feature. See [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool) for more information.

To solve this, try using a master-slave database gem like [octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus).